# Performing functions against an entire directory of files

Tags: python, networking

**How do I best run a function (eventually multiple functions) against a directory of files?**  In this specific example, I am trying to run the function against each file individually, so it only needs to run on one file at a time.  Long term I want to have scripts that will check for things more holistically, but for now one at a time suffices.

In my current case, it will be outputs of network devices.  For instance, below takes an output from "show cdp neighbor detail" on a switch and cleans up the output slightly.

The variable "thefile" is used to run against a single file, but I need to run against any different number of files in a directory.  Multiple scripts?  Some kind of os.walk() code in this script?

```
hostcheck = "hostname"
devicecheck = "Device ID"
ipaddresscheck = "IP address"
platformcheck = "Platform"
interfacecheck = "Interface"
hyphencheck = "---"

thefile = "core-cdp-detail.log"

with open(thefile) as search:
    for line in search:
        line = line.rstrip()  # remove '\n' at end of line
        if hostcheck in line:
            hostentry = line.split("hostname ")[1]
            print("Below CDP information is from " + hostentry)
        elif devicecheck in line:
            print("Remote " + line)
        elif ipaddresscheck in line:
            print("Remote " + line.lstrip())
        elif platformcheck in line:
            print(line.split(",")[0])
        elif interfacecheck in line:
            print("Remote Interface: " + line.split("port):")[1])
        elif hyphencheck in line:
            print(line)
            print("\n")
            print("Local Device ID: " + hostentry)
```

Comment: you mean loop on `glob.glob("*.log")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob('*.log'):
    with open(file) as search:
        ...
```

(or whatever files you want to perform this on, you could replace `'*.log'` by `'*.*'` or `'logs/*.log'` etc.)

For more info see the docs on the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

you can traverse directory using `os.walk`

```
import os

hostcheck = "hostname"
devicecheck = "Device ID"
ipaddresscheck = "IP address"
platformcheck = "Platform"
interfacecheck = "Interface"
hyphencheck = "---"


def check_content(file_path):
    with open(thefile) as search:
        for line in search:
            line = line.rstrip()  # remove '\n' at end of line
            if hostcheck in line:
                hostentry = line.split("hostname ")[1]
                print("Below CDP information is from " + hostentry)
            elif devicecheck in line:
                print("Remote " + line)
            elif ipaddresscheck in line:
                print("Remote " + line.lstrip())
            elif platformcheck in line:
                print(line.split(",")[0])
            elif interfacecheck in line:
                print("Remote Interface: " + line.split("port):")[1])
            elif hyphencheck in line:
                print(line)
                print("\n")


def check_dir_content(dir_path):

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
        for file in files:
            check_content(os.path.join(subdir, file))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_dir_content('/Users/gaurang.shah/Documents')
```

Comment: I tried this code, and it completes with exit code 0, but the output isn't getting printed.  Under the check_content function it says "with open(thefile)."  I had previously configured thefile as a variable but it's not in the response.  Should it be "file?"  If so, that does not produce output either.  Thoughts?

Comment: @tjp what you need to do is call `check_dir_content` function and pass the path of the directory in which you have files on which you want to run your code.  I have updated the question, hope that will help/